# Does enabling cPHulk from within WHM protect my entire server?

Tags: ssh, brute-force-attacks

So I have enabled cPHulk on my web server, and just realized now that somebody (most likely a bot) is attempting to brute force their way into my WHM, thus leaving me out as well.

I was shown this message when attempting to login to my WHM from the IP I always use:

> This account is currently locked out because a brute force attempt was
>   detected. Please wait a few minutes and try again. Attempting to login
>   again will only increase this delay. If you frequently experience this
>   problem, we recommend having your username changed to something less
>   generic.

So I am simply curious. Since somebody is obviously attempting to brute force my WHM, could they also be attempting to brute force my SSH? And does cPHulk protect SSH as well?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cPHulk also protects SSH yes. But I always use cPHulk in combination with [CSF/LFD](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html)

Also in case you're locked out of your server try this:
https://www.example.com:2087/usr/local/cpanel/scripts2/doautofixer?autofix=disable_cphulk

[Source](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CPHulk)